# Connecting with websockets to windows azure using MVC controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, azure, websocket

I'm trying to do the example here:
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/programming-html5-web-sockets-in-asp.net-4.5.htm (but with a little twist, I use an MVC controller as the gate for establishing a web socket connection)

This is my controller in mvc4:

```
public class HandleWSController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /HandleWS/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Inside IsWebSocketRequest check");
            ControllerContext.HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(DoTalking);                
        }


        return View();
    }

    public async Task DoTalking(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Inside DoTalking");
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
        while (true)
        {
            var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            Trace.WriteLine("Result: " + result.ToString());
            Trace.WriteLine("State: " + socket.State.ToString());
            if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                string userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                userMessage = "You sent: " + userMessage + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                Trace.WriteLine(userMessage);
                buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userMessage));
                await socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

This is my view from which I try to connect:

```
 <h2>Index</h2>
 <input type="text" id="txtMsg" placeholder="Write your message here" /><input type="submit" id="btnSend" value="Send" /><input type="submit" id="btnStop" value="Stop" />

 <div id="divHistory">

 </div>
<script>

var socket;
$(document).ready(function () {
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://wstester.azurewebsites.net/HandleWS/Index");
    socket.onopen = function (evt) {
        $("#divHistory").html('<h3>Connection Opened with the Echo server.</h3> ');
    }   
    socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
        $("#divHistory").html('<h3>' + evt.data + '</h3> ');
    }   
    socket.onerror = function (evt) {
        $("#divHistory").html('<h3>Unexpected Error.</h3> ');
    }
});



$("#btnSend").click(function () {
    if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
        socket.send($("#txtMsg").val());
    }
    else {
        $("#divHistory").append('<h3>The underlying connection is closed.</h3> ');
    }
});


$("#btnStop").click(function () {
    socket.close();
});
 </script>
```

As you can see I've been trying to use trace to find out wher the error is. The trace "Inside IsWebSocketRequest check" is logged but the trace inside the DoTalking method is not.

I get the "The underlying connection is closed" message when I try to run it. Web sockets is enabled for this web site on azure. I dont know the port but then since I am using a controller in mvc I figured port 80 should be the default anyway. My teacher took a quick look at this and couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Any help or pointer would be appreciated!

Comment: Anything you wish me to add to this question, something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line in Index method to `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Inside IsWebSocketRequest check");
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(DoTalking);
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
}
```

Comment: The solution works. See this: http://meegoreng.azurewebsites.net/. I looked at your solution in http://wstester.azurewebsites.net/ and found that your WebSocket is trying to connect to localhost instead of the azure website! Also, recheck if you enabled websockets in azure.

Comment: You can download the source code at my test site meegoreng.azurewebsites.net.